# Unit-testing side-effects in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, side-effects

I have a function that pulls messages from an AMPQ message bus:

```
(defn get-message [queue client]
    (let [msg (mq/get-message client queue)]
    (if msg
        (logit msg))))
```

mq/get-message and logit are both side-effects, one depends on network access, the other on disk IO on the local machine.

Is there an idiomatic way of unit-testing side-effects in Clojure?  My first thought was mocks/stubs, but if there was something better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `core.test` I usually go the way of mocking up the side effectish functions using `with-redefs`

```
(deftest ampq-messaing
  "Test messaging"
  (let [logit-msg (atom nil)]
    (with-redefs [mq/get-message (fn [] "message")
                  logit (fn [msg] 
                           (reset! logit-msg msg))]
      (let [response (your-test-trigger)]
        (is (= "message" @logit-msg))))))
```

In that case I'm testing the returned message from `mq` is the one used in `logit`, and I'm assuming that `your-test-trigger` is something that triggers a call to `get-message`.